# How to create Text File from fragment using toggle button

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app for office purpose and I want to store the latitude and longitude into a file.
So for the user i have implemented "Navigation Drawer Activity" in the navigation drawer activity home fragment is present in that home fragment I have a toggle button which act as "Check-In" and "Check-Out" Button.
If the user press the check-out toggle button there should be a text file create in device or in firebase database which contain the latitude and longitude.

The problem is I cant able to create text file in fragment.
please give me some solution.

I am expecting to create a file in fragment or in firebase database.

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.